# Cannot set OnGlobalLayoutListener again in fragment after coming bac from another fragment Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I set `OnGlobalLayoutListener` to detect softkeyboard event (hide or show softkeyboard) in `fragment` in `onActivityCreated()`. It was ok if i didn't go to `fragment`.

```
private void setGlobalLayoutListener() {    
    View rootView = getView().findViewById(R.id.root_view);
        onGlobalLayoutListener = new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout(){ 
                     //do st here
                }
    };
    activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(onGlobalLayoutListener);
}
```

Then I go to another `fragment` to do something, and comeback, i call `setGlobalLayoutListener()` again in `onActivityCreated()` but it doesn't run to `onGlobalLayout()` when i show or hide softkeyboard. Any suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
final View activityRootView = findViewById(R.id.activityRoot);
activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        int heightDiff = activityRootView.getRootView().getHeight() - activityRootView.getHeight();
        if (heightDiff > dpToPx(this, 200)) { // if more than 200 dp, it's probably a keyboard...
            // ... do something here
        }
     }
});
```

Using a utility such as:

```
public static float dpToPx(Context context, float valueInDp) {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    return TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, valueInDp, metrics);
}
```

**Note:** You must set this flag in Android Manifest `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` 
otherwise this solution will not work.

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Thank you! I set `windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in Android Manifest, and set this flag to `adjustResize` in `onCreate()`, so when come back from another `fragment`, the flag cannot be changed. So now i change this flage in `onResume()` and it works perfectly.